# Constraint error on delete in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I've got the following EF model:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IList<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The primary key of `OrderLine` is made of `OrderId` and `Position`:

```
HasKey(l => new {l.Position, l.OrderId});
```

Everything worked well so far, until I added this new entity:

```
public class OrderLineReturn
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public IList<OrderLineReturn> LineReturns { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And now I get an error when deleting orders:

```
DELETE instruction is in conflict with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.OrderLineReturn_dbo.OrderLine_OrderLine_Position_OrderLine_OrderId"
```

Could anyone help me understand the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you need to mark the ILIst property as virtual to enable Lazy loading. Also, I wonder if you need to make a Virtual Order Property in OrderLine instead of having the OrderID reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm correct, but I think that you would have the same problem if you tried to delete an Order without deleting first it's OrderLines.

The problem is that OrderLineReturn will have a reference to the OrderLine, and when you delete the OrderLine without first deleting the OrderLineReturn it will give you that error.

I think you can enable cascade deleting...but it's always a risk.

Regards,